# Understanding an argument involving Holder spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces, holder-inequality

I'm trying to better understand the following argument:

*The function $u$ is in $L^q(M)$ for some $q > 2^\star=\frac{2n}{n-2}$. By standard elliptic theory, the $u$ is in $C^{2,\theta}(M)$, $0 < \theta < 1$.*

It appears at the end of page 11 of this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507358.pdf).

---

I'm trying to use, but without success, the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Etan/Sobolev%20Space/5.6.1.pdf).

Comment: what does $q>2^*$ mean? Btw you misquoted the article; it's talking about a whole family of $u_i$. (does that matter? i have no idea)

Comment: I will try to clarify more. But it seems to me that it's a general argument.

Comment: well, $f\in L^q$ simply does not imply that $f$ is continuous, so there must be _something_ going on that you haven't told us...

Comment: Isn't it basically the standard elliptic estimate applied to each component of (1.1)?  You have $\Delta u_i\in L^q$, so the standard $L^q$ elliptic (+ a priori) estimate $\lVert u_i\rVert_{L^q_2}\leq C(\lVert f\rVert_{L^q}+\lVert u\rVert_{L^q})$ etc until you get $u\in L^q_k(M)$ for high enough $k$ to get in $C^{0,\alpha}$, etc.